# flutter web not working because of internet restrictions on googleusercontent.com

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I have two flutter web apps running on IIS 8 and they stopped working a few days ago and I discovered that the cause is that the PC does not have internet access (it is a domain pc, with user restrictions), but this starting happening a few days ago (it was working, I think a flutter upgrade or dart upgrade was the cause, I don't know exactly), and the console log says that something could not be found at googleusercontent.com...

So, the TI member put a new rule on firewall to allow this address and the app started working again.

Why my app can't run because of this and a few days ago it was working?  Is this a new restriction or my company changed firewall rules?? Does Flutter Web apps needs internet connection to work?

The apps are too simple, does not have any sign in of firebase, the libs that I am using are:

```
  url_launcher: ^6.0.3
  transparent_image: ^2.0.0
  http: ^0.13.1
  scoped_model: ^1.1.0
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.5
  shared_preferences_web: ^2.0.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.4
```

Versions:

```
Flutter 2.0.4 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision b1395592de (4 weeks ago) • 2021-04-01 14:25:01 -0700
Engine • revision 2dce47073a
Tools • Dart 2.12.2
```

If you know something about this to teach me, I'll appreciate
Thanks